# 389 directory server error "Operation requires a secure connection"

Tags: ldap, directory, 389-ds

I have installed a directory server but I can't change the password of user. I have used this command:

> [root@xxxx]# ldappasswd -x -D
>   "cn=directory manager" -W
>   "uid=xxxxx,ou=xxxx,dc=xxx,dc=xx" -S
>
> New password:
>
> Re-enter new password:
>
> Enter LDAP Password:
>
> Result: Confidentiality required (13)
>
> Additional info: Operation requires a
>   secure connection.

*Important:* This command works on OpenLDAP, I've already tested!
Where is the error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The message "Additional info: Operation requires a secure connection." is quite obvious, isn't it?

Comment: is not obvious! I did not put special restrictions when I configured the server ... Nor should I be forced to change passwords with a "secure connection" ... Indeed this problem "secure connection" with openldap  does not exist .. otherwise, you think, because there is the "-x"??

Comment: @Emanuele - Changing passwords over an insecure connection is a really bad idea, so having it as a default requirement simply makes sense. Forget about what you can or can't do with a different product, as it's completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation on the product. It appears that by default is does require security. That is a difference between 389 and OpenLDAP. If they were supposed to be exactly the same, then no one would have bothered forking 389 off into a different project, right?

Edit -

Despite your protestation below, "Read the documentation" is a great answer, and it's clear that you didn't. [The end of this page explicitly tells you that you must use TLS with ldappasswd](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/dir-server/ag/7.1/password.htm)

> This operation supports Start TLS encryption (-ZZ[Z]), and you must use a secure connection for the password change operation.

Comment: 389DS didn't originate from OpenLDAP, its the result of Red Hat buying and open sourcing Netscape DS.

Comment: Reading further, you're correct. Because the OP was asking why 389 didn't work exactly the same as OpenLDAP, I wrongly assumed that the former was derived from the latter. Since they're not related, it only makes my point stronger : don't assume they operate the same.

Answer (score 0):

ldappasswd cannot be used with non-ssl connections. Do you have your fedora-ds configured with SSL, If not use below link to configure your fedora-ds on ssl

http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/389-users/2012-March/014200.html

After configuring fedora-ds on ssl, use below for start_tls

> ldappasswd -x -ZZ

or below to start ssl

> ldappasswd -h ldaps://server.exmaple.com